# Custom menu in wordpress is not being styled

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to add a custom menu in my wordpress theme that I am creating from scratch (with the help of an online tutorial). I've created the menu, added the location to my theme, and there are links now displaying in my theme however they are not being styled at all. This is what my functions.php file looks like:

```
<?php

    add_theme_support ('menus');

    function register_theme_menus () {

        register_nav_menus(
             array (
                    'primary-menu' => _('Primary Menu')  
             )
        );
    };

add_action ('init', 'register_theme_menus');

function twp_theme_styles() {

     wp_enqueue_style ('normaliz_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normaliz.css');

     wp_enqueue_style ('normaliz_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normaliz.css');

     wp_enqueue_style ('googlefont', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' );

     wp_enqueue_style ('main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twp_theme_styles');

?>
```

and here is where I put the wp_nav_menu() function in my CSS:

```
    <?php

             $defaults = array(
                'containter' => 'nav',
                'container_id' => 'mainNav',
                'theme_location' => 'primary-Menu',
                'menu_id' => 'mainNavUl'
             );

             wp_nav_menu($defaults);

    ?>  
         <!--
               <nav id="mainNav">


                   <ul id="mainNavUl">
                       <li class="mainNavLi"><a href="homePage.html">Home</a></li>
                       <li class="mainNavLi"><a href="">HTML</a>
                            <ul class="subNavUl">
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Beginner</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Intermediate</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Advanced</a></li>
                            </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="mainNavLi"><a href="">CSS</a>
                            <ul class="subNavUl">
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Beginner</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Intermediate</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Advanced</a></li>
                            </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="mainNavLi"><a href="">Javascript</a>
                            <ul class="subNavUl">
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Beginner</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Intermediate</a></li>
                                <li class="subNavLi"><a href="">Advanced</a></li>
                            </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>

               </nav>
              -->
```

I've commented out my original CSS since that is what was recommend by the tutorial. Any thoughts? Any help is much obliged.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? When you view source on the page, is the css file which contains the styles corresponding to the menu being loaded correctly? Could be a file path issue but hard to troubleshoot without seeing the site.

Comment: okay, ya the site isn't live on the web as I'm working locally on it currently. So from what I provided though your saying you don't see anything that should cause the issue I'm having? That would help so that I know more where to look for the problem

Comment: I think where above you say '...in my css', you mean 'in my php'. Is the wp_nav_menu() function outputting the HTML for your menu? If it's just the style that's not being loaded, perhaps you could try manually loading the stylesheet in the header with <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/theme/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> - not ideal but might help you to start troubleshooting. Again, hard to know without seeing the site.

Comment: I understand. And when I inspect the element on my webpage it's saying that the id "mainNav" is being applied with a class of "menu" although it's inside a div tag instead of a nav tag that I specified. There is also a ul tag with the id of "mainNavUl" and a class of "menu" being applied below the div so I guess that's being applied okay as well. Although, after looking at my html do you think that because I have classes applied to my list items that maybe that is causing the problems?

Comment: ah-ha! That was the problem. Thank you for helping me work out my problem. Good stuff.

Comment: No probs - glad you got it sorted.